# Postgres group and aggregate(sum) JSONb arrays and non JSONb properties

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, aggregate, json

**Version**
PostgreSQL 11.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc, a 224fe214a p 3971489d3e, 64-bit

I am trying to build a query which (distinctly) groups values from JSONb columns, and also sums values from others, and non JSONb columns.

**Table Definition** (I have removed other columns that are not relevant)

```
id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
casualties jsonb NOT NULL,
involved_parties jsonb NULL,
tags jsonb NULL,
reported_at int8 NULL,
```

**casualities**

Each row has a single object which represents the count of casualties across categories, for the incident.

```
{"police_deaths": 0, "civilian_deaths": 0, "criminal_deaths": 0, "military_deaths": 0, "police_injuries": 0, "emergency_deaths": 0, "civilian_injuries": 1, "criminal_injuries": 1, "military_injuries": 0, "emergency_injuries": 0}
```

**involved_parties**

This is an array of objects.  Each row shows zero or more involved parties (who was involved in the incident).  The data looks a little misleading at first as for each entry within the array the involved party/incident relationship has an ID.  This doesnt really give us anything and I dont need this, but it is in the data currently.

```
[
  {"id": "2a0fd9dc-40bd-40dc-88ce-bc819fe9cdd8", "type": "group", "group": {"id": "6d342bfc-72c4-4588-ab95-1b3bdfb4881a", "name": "Naxals"}, "involvement": "Actor"}, 
  {"id": "dafc4726-3d3d-40cb-bbaf-63fa57250b44", "type": "group", "group": {"id": "18c6d3f6-c3eb-45db-9a02-26606f85d7eb", "name": "Indian Security Forces"}, "involvement": "Directly Targeted"}
]
```

Its the group, and involvement data I am interested in here.

**affected sectors**

This structure is much like the involved parties.

```
[
  {"id": "fcb952ef-3139-4fe7-ba15-7d800bdc60ae", "sector": {"id": "668d330e-aee5-4291-be98-df9c32b5b420", "name": "Military"}}, 
  {"id": "d1b71bae-29ac-48a2-ab41-a6979d720171", "sector": {"id": "550a4aa0-6d6f-4be2-ba33-f35d159ee686", "name": "Police/Law"}}
]
```

Here it is the sector I am interested in.

**reported_at**

This is the epoch representation of when the incident was reported by our analysts.

**Desired Output**

For the records in the query I want a single row.
The single row has the following columns:

```
incident_count,
casualties,
involved_parties,
tags,
min_reported_at,
max_reported_at
```

The incident count should be just that, the number of rows formally represented.

The casualties object always has the same properties in the JSON and I want to sum them.  So, there will be a single object with the sum of all police_deaths, civilian_deaths etc.

For the involved parties and affected sectors; each should have a single array containing a unique set of the parties/sectors from the rows

Min/Max reported at should be the min/max over all rows.

I tried from this starting point:

```sql
select 
    jsonb_agg(incidents.affected_sectors) as affected_sectors,
    jsonb_agg(incidents.involved_parties) as involved_parties
from incidents
```

But this was painfully slow (9 seconds). So I then tried by expanding each object out to a row, then trying to collapse it back but got lost off and bad results.

I'd appreciate any pointers here

Thanks,

Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i've got a working query that is happening in an acceptable timeframe.  It feels ugly, so if there are obvious ways I can improve it please do let me know.

```sql
with base_data as (
        /*This is where the query for incidents/static assets goes*/
        select affected_sectors, involved_parties, reported_at, tags, casualties 
        from incidents
        ------------------------------------------------------------
)
select  /*unique affected_sectors*/ 
        (
            select jsonb_agg(ssect.sector)
            from (
                select sect.sector
                from base_data,
                 jsonb_to_recordset(base_data.affected_sectors) as sect(id varchar, sector jsonb)
                group by sect.sector
                ) ssect
        ) unique_sectors,
        /*unique involved parties*/
        (
            select jsonb_agg(spart.group)
            from    (
                select grp."group"
                from base_data,
                jsonb_to_recordset(base_data.involved_parties) as grp(id varchar, "type" varchar, "group" jsonb, involvement varchar)
                group by grp."group"
            ) spart
        ) unique_groups,
        /*min reported at date*/
        (
            select min(reported_at) from base_data 
        ) min_reported_at,
        /*max reported at date*/
        (
            select max(reported_at) from base_data 
        ) max_reported_at,
        /*unique tags*/
        (
            select jsonb_agg(stags.tags)
            from    (
                select value tags 
                from base_data, 
                jsonb_array_elements(base_data.tags) 
                group by value
            ) stags
        ) unique_tags,
        /*summary casualty counts*/
        (
            select json_object_agg(key, val)
            from (
                select key, sum(value::numeric) val
                from base_data cas, jsonb_each_text(cas.casualties)
                group by key
                ) scas
        ) casualty_counts,
        /*Incident Count*/
        (
            select count(1) from base_data
        ) incident_count
```

In our database this runs in around 700ms for 10000 incidents on a clear cache.
I'd have liked this to be sub 200ms and will continue to hack at it.  If I come up with anything more useful I'll add a comment.